# Apply CSS to disabled input button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

```
    <input type="button" value="Share" id="buttonShareMap" style="float:right; width:68px;" disabled="disabled"/> 

/* Only enable 'SHARE' btns if a checkbox is selected */
         var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
            submitButtShare = $("#buttonShareMap");

         checkboxes.click(function () {
             submitButtShare.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
         });
```

This code works fine, only enabling the button if a check box is clicked. However I want to use the css classes 'class="edit red btn"', and although the functionality is still working the button appears visible.

I would like to add one css class if button is enabled and another if it is disabled...How Can I do this? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a new css class here:

```
submitButtShare.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked")).toggleClass('disabled');
```

now in the css you can use this:

```
#buttonShareMap.disabled{
    background:#c5c5c5;
    color:#ddd;
}
```

checkout the sample demo:

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  $('#buttonShareMap').prop('disabled', this.checked).toggleClass('disabled');
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
  background:#0ff;
}
#buttonShareMap.disabled {
  background: #c5c5c5;
  color: #ddd;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='buttonShareMap' class='red' value='buttonShareMap' />
<input type='checkbox' />
```

Comment: I think instead of  ' . ' you need to add ' : '

Comment: that is a new css class not a pseudo selector.

Comment: @stanze that means this `#buttonShareMap.disabled` looks for an element in the dom with an id and a class as well. so in this case it would be `<input type="button" value="Share" id="buttonShareMap" class='disabled' style="float:right; width:68px;" disabled="disabled"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Just check the button disabled attr or just the checkbox checked value and set    classes accordingly. Below I have used the checkbox state.

```
     checkboxes.click(function () {
         submitButtShare.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
         if(checkboxes.is(":checked"))
         {
              submitButtShare.addClass('ifButtonEnabled')
              .removeClass('ifButtoDisabled');

         }
         else
         {
             submitButtShare.addClass('ifButtoDisabled')
             .removeClass('ifButtonEnabled');

         }
     });
```

Comment: your code is wrong, because if the user 'check' and 'uncheck' the checkbox, it's going to keep both classes, you have to replace the class not add a class.

Comment: Your are right. Just trying to keep the solution precise.

Comment: no problem :). I have edited your code because you can do all in one line. Also you can take a look my answer. it's like what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

you can set background color for disable elements, by using below code.

```
#buttonShareMap:disabled {
    background: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Helo,

I have made an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/o82tfxrb/1/

js:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ck').on('change', function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')){
             $('#buttonShareMap').removeClass('red')
             .addClass('blue');
            }else{
                $('#buttonShareMap').removeClass('blue')
             .addClass('red');
            }
        });
    });
```

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ck" /> 
<input type="button" class="red" value="Share" id="buttonShareMap"/>
```

css:

```
.red{
    background-color:red;
}

.blue{
    background-color:blue;
    color: white;
}
```

What I am doing is check everytime the user change the checkbox and then I add a class.

I hope it's helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the HTML

```
<input disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-blue span3" type="submit" value="Change">
```

Here is the CSS

```
input[disabled].btn:hover,input[disabled].btn:hover,input[disabled].btn:focus{
color:yellow}
```